# Magento 2.3.4 Google ReCaptcha error even after deleting the ReCaptcha code from my file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

I have implemented Google ReCaptcha in one of my custom contact forms but that did not work as expected. So, I decided to delete all files related to this page ReCaptcha. I even deleted all the files still the captcha validation error "You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low." is showing. Is there any place do I need to delete anything to avoid this error? Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

@shanker

Please run below sql query at database side

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%capt%';
```

You will found a result. Check if still captcha is enabled then disable it from database and check.

Might be will help you.

Comment: Hi @Darshan I wanted to disable only for that one custom form reCAPTCHA and other Recaptchas like login, create user etc.. should work with Recaptcha only. I deleted my custom contact page recaptcha entry from database already.

Comment: @shankarboss if you want to disable for that form only then need to remove captcha code from that custom form. And from that controller file accept post request without validate captcha.

Comment: ok @Darshan. I have two forms with same destination/post URL in the form action. Example Form-A & Form-B. In Form A the reCAPTCHA is working fine because that form has a layout handler and Form B is a custom CMS page, so it doesn't have layout handler. I called the recaptcha in custom cms page phtml by direct calling get->block()->getLayout() statement. Recaptcha is showing but it is showing recaptcha validation error. So I decided to delete the recaptcha from Form B but even I delete all the code related to Recaptcha from form B the validation error message is still showing.

Comment: Is that because of both Form A & Form B having same controller/action path or something else in database I am not sure.